# Determining if the HTTP scheme is https or http in mod_perl2?

Tags: perl, apache, mod-perl2

I need to work out if an incoming request is using SSL in a mod_perl environment - how can I do this reliably?

Answer (score 3):

Compare [`scheme`](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/APR/URI.html#C_scheme_) with `https`.